# In a byte addressed space with 32bit addressing, it takes up 32bits of memory to reference 8 bits?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

In a byte addressed space with 32bit addressing,  it takes up 32bits of memory to reference 8 bits?

So the addressing is the major portion of Memory?

Am I conceptualizing this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It takes 32 bits to reference a contiguous region of any size. If you have a 1 megabyte buffer, you're not going to store a pointer to every byte inside it, you'll just store a pointer to the beginning of it.

Comment: That's what I though.

So then what is the deal with a multi level page table.

We're studying it in O.S. class but I don't get the reason for it.

Comment: Ah ok looking into it. That's a separate subject. Thanks for the info. :)

Comment: @user1821450 Multi-level page tables are used to vastly reduce the amount of memory occupied by page tables in certain circumstances. A 32-bit address space split into 4KB pages gives 1Mi pages - a 64-bit page table entry (I don't remember what x86 uses off the top of my head) would require 8MB of your memory, just for the page tables, and there is typically one page table per process, so most of your memory would go to page tables if a sparse hierarchical format were not used.

Comment: OK gotcha.  So I think was conceptualizing how addressing works wrong.
In real mode memory you don't actually need to map the entire address space into software to be able to reference anything.  It's all done at the hardware level.  A program just needs to keep track of it's own address spaces.  

For some reason I was thinking that there needed to be a mapping to every single byte in software.  Page tables are JUST to keep track of pages. 


THANKS for the help!  This site is amazing.